# Can't compile VLC android on Windows 10 android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, vlc, vlc-android

I tried to compile the latest code of VLC android on Windows 10 android studio but when tried to open it, it showed the error --

> Error: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.

I have searched the web and found some answers like NDK install, JDK latest version path setup. I tried all but still getting the same error.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found that VLC android can't be compiled on Windows. It can be compiled only on Linux or OSX.

[VLC Android Compile Requirements](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/#Requirements)